# How to vertical-align:middle a picture with text?

Tags: html, css

This is my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YrYH6/2/

How can I align the Facebook and Twitter icons with the *Logout* text?

**CSS:**

```
#header_bg {
    background: #444444;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
#header {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/HXC7Q.png") repeat-x scroll center bottom transparent;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header_bg">&nbsp;</div>
    <open style="font-size: 0.7em; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); float: right; margin-top: 7px; margin-right: 75px;">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/pYAtH.png"></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/LnMhg.png"></a>
        <a href="#" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Logout</a>
    </open>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the <open>. Never came across that element. JUst put all the <a> in a container div and float left. Remmber to clear the float as well. - http://jsfiddle.net/U4qav/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution, which requires no change to the markup is just to use:

```
a,img{vertical-align:middle}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/YrYH6/4/

For finer tuning, the alignment seems a bit better if you do this:

```
img{vertical-align:top}
a{vertical-align:middle}
```

Comment: @jason: Well it seems so rare that we get to use it! It should just work on every element!

Answer (score 0):

I put the link in a `span` and then applied these styles

```
span{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:0;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/YrYH6/3/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the open elements, float the a to the left and apply margins - http://jsfiddle.net/edY2Y/

Comment: the way you phrased it made it look like you'd already done it!

Comment: Oh Ok. I deserve a downvote. I made a comment at the very beggining though.

Comment: If you're accusing me of downvoting, I didn't.

Comment: lol. No Eric. I am not accusinng you of downvoting. And even if you or somebody else did it, I deserve it. Let's give it a rest. And yes, you are right. I should have removed the "open" after suggesting it to be removed. Dont't see any downvotes to my answer anways. Thanks.